# Select ID from customers that do not have contacts last 7 days and 2 times in the month

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, plsql, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables: customer, c_contact. 
c_contact is all the e-mails I send to my customers.
From now on I need to put a new rule that the customer can't receive a new e-mail if: 
1) It received an e-mail in the last 7 days
2) Have 2 or more e-mails sent in the current month

I thought something like that:

```
SELECT * from customer c inner join c_contact cc on cc.ID = c.ID WHERE
ID not in (select ID from c_contact c1 where c1.ID = cc.ID and 
c1.CONTDATE >= getdate()-7) AND
ID not in (select count(ID) from c_contact where MONTH(contdate) = MONTH(getdate()) 
and YEAR(contdate) = YEAR(getdate() HAVING count(ID) >= 2)
```

But the table c_contact is huge and it taking ages to run this.
Is there a way to do these 2 conditions in 1 "ID not in"? I think it will run a lot faster.

Comment: Do you have an index on the `CONTDATE` field? It could help tremendously.

Comment: "ID" is index on both tables.

Comment: `ID` is the primary key. However, you can add an index to the `CONTDATE` column to speed up querying against those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how much better this would be performance wise, but off the top of my head you could do this.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    customer c
        OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) monthCount 
                     FROM   c_contact cc 
                     WHERE  cc.ID = c.ID 
                            AND cc.contdate >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
                            AND cc.contdate < DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)) ct
        OUTER APPLY (SELECT MAX(cc.contdate) lastSent 
                     FROM   c_contact cc 
                     WHERE  cc.ID = c.ID AND cc.contdate < GETDATE()) ls
WHERE   ct.monthCount < 2
        AND ls.lastSent < DATEADD(dd, -7, GETDATE())
```

Or, using a left join instead of 2 outer applies, you can try:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    customer c
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT  cc.ID, 
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(cc.contdate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) THEN 1 END) monthCount,
                    MAX(cc.contdate) lastSent
            FROM    c_contact cc
            WHERE   cc.contdate BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, -32, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
            GROUP BY cc.ID
        ) cc ON c.ID = cc.ID
WHERE   ISNULL(cc.monthCount,0) < 2
        AND ISNULL(cc.lastSent,GETDATE()) < DATEADD(dd, -7, GETDATE())
```

if you really just want to use `NOT IN` you can try:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    customer c
WHERE   c.ID NOT IN (
            SELECT  cc.ID, 
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(cc.contdate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) THEN 1 END) monthCount,
                    MAX(cc.contdate) lastSent
            FROM    c_contact cc
            WHERE   cc.contdate BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, -32, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
            GROUP BY cc.ID
            HAVING  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(cc.contdate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) THEN 1 END) > 1
                    AND MAX(cc.contdate) >  DATEADD(dd, -7, GETDATE()) 
        )
```

Comment: Brilliant. The 3 options seens to work for me.
The last one is what I was trying to do. But now I will test wich one is faster.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done in other way:

```
select A.* from Customers A
where A.CustID not in (
select B.CustID from (
(select C.CustID, Count(C.CustID) cnt from Contacts C
where C.ContactedDate >=GETDATE()-7 group by C.CustID)
UNION
(select C.CustID, Count(C.CustID) cnt from Contacts C
where C.ContactedDate <=GETDATE()-7 and Month(C.ContactedDate) = Month(GETDATE()) and YEAR(C.ContactedDate)= YEAR(GETDATE()) 
group by C.CustID having COUNT(C.CustID) >= 2)) B);
go
```

Divide customer IDs into two sets- the first set containing IDs that were contacted in the recent 7 days, and the second set containing IDs that were contacted in the last three weeks of the current month. Take `UNION` of these two sets to finally exclude while selecting the desired set of customers.